# XLSX Angular export sheet from nested array in one sheet

Tags: javascript, json, angular, excel, xlsx

I am using this package [xlsx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx)

Wanted to export nested array of object export in excel sheet example added below, please help!

```
let data = [
    {
    "product": "Test Product",
    "id": 1,
    "childProduct": [
        { name: "Child Product 1", "id": 11 },
        { name: "Child Product 2", "id": 12 }
    ]
},
{
    "product": "Test Product",
    "id": 1,
    "childProduct": [
        { "name": "Child Product 1", "id": 13 },
        { "name": "Child Product 2", "id": 14 }
    ]
}
]
```

I have tried this solutions, but it isn't work it always replace last data.

```
let wb = xlsx.utils.book_new();
data.map((item: any) => {
  xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(item.childProduct);
})
```

**Single sheet should be like this:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
let dummyArray =[]
    data.map((dat)=>{
      dat.childProduct.forEach((x)=>{
        dummyArray.push(x)
      })
    });
xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(dummyArray)
```

This is for simple format.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a more elegant way to do this with built-in xlsx library methods, but you can transform data to get desired output.

Array you pass into `json_to_sheet` function has to be structured like this:

```
[
  { "name": "Child Product 1", "id": 11 },
  { "name": "Child Product 2", "id": 12 },
  { "name": "--", "id": "--" },
  { "name": "name", "id": "id" },
  { "name": "Child Product 1", "id": 13 },
  { "name": "Child Product 2", "id": 14 }
]
```

Transform data into new array for export:

```
const exportData = data.map((item, i) => {
  if (data.length !== i+1) {
    item.childProduct.push({"id": "--", "name": "--"});
    item.childProduct.push({"id": "id", "name": "name"});
  }
  return item.childProduct;
}).flat();
```

Export data using library:

```
xlsx.utils.json_to_sheet(exportData);
```

Comment: The Data is dynamic not static